# kong request transformer invoke multiple microservice APIs

Tags: kong, kong-plugin

I am exploring Kong. I am wondering if I can achieve the following scenario using request transformer plugin.

- A request is reached at the request transformer plugin.
- Split the request into three microservice API requests.
- Call the three APIs sequentially.
- Merge the response of all three APIs.
- Send the response back.

Answer (score 3):

I think that is not possible as Kong is not an orchestration/business process/ESB tool. I see two solutions for this use case:

- Deploy a BPM engine like Camunda, which takes care of orchestrating services
- Create your own service which does the calls for you and merges the responses